# How do I make my React app work on Edge and IE 11?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

My react has been working fine, but I decided to try it on Edge and Chrome and on both browsers I get a syntax error when it loads. The app was written using create-react-app, and when I discovered it wasn't working on Windows, I did the following:

- Installed `react-app-polyfill`
- Updated my browser list in `package.json` to include `ie 11` and `last 1 edge`
- imported `react-app-polyfill/stable` and `react-app-polyfill/ie11` in `index.js`
- Deleted `node_modules/.cache`

and restarted `npm start` but both Edge and IE 11 dev tools console show syntax errors:
[image: IE 11 syntax error]
but they show different line numbers for some odd reason. In desperation, I also tried deleting all of `node_modules` and running `npm install` again. Still no help.

If I do a production build and serve, some pages seem to work and others I get errors in IE and Edge complaining about trying to do `map` or `length` on nulls.

Comment: Install ‘es-check’ and run it against your compiled build folder. It’ll tell you which chunk doesn’t conform to ES5. It may require some digging, but chances are it’ll be a npm package that decided to drop support for IE11 and moved their codebase to ES6. From there you’ll have to alter your webpack configuration to have ‘babel-loader’ to transpile that particular node_module.

Comment: Here's an example script using `es-check`: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/SJSITApp/blob/master/client/package.json#L16 and here's how you can include (exclude from `node_modules`) a particular package that needs to be transpiled (in my case, `d3-scale` was ES6, so in production, I specify `babel-loader` to include it): https://github.com/mattcarlotta/SJSITApp/blob/master/client/config/rules.js#L83

Comment: What is your `react-scripts` version? It seems to be an issue with `react-scripts` version 3.3.0 and higher. You could find many issue reports in GitHub, for example: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195. It can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`. You could try to revert back to 3.2.0 as a workaround.

Comment: @MattCarlotta es-check is complaining about build/service-worker.js. I don't even know where that comes from.

Comment: Remove the service worker. Check the main `index.js` and unregister it and/or remove its import. Here's an example tree structure (`serviceWorker.js` sits at root): https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-single-bundle/tree/master/src and here's the line you'll want to remove from `index.js`: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-single-bundle/blob/master/src/index.js#L5-L12 (L5 & L12)

Comment: In addition, after removing it from your code, make sure to clear your browser cache, as the service worker will still be active.

Comment: @MattCarlotta I'd already deleted the serviceWorker.js out of the project and deleted the import and the call, but I tried again and cleared the cache and everything, and it still fails. I'm going to try the other suggestion to roll back react-scripts. Thanks so much for your patience so far.

Comment: @YuZhou that did it! Thanks. Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: @PaulTomblin OK, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with `react-scripts` version 3.3.0 and higher. You could find many issue reports in GitHub, for example: [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

It can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`. You could try to revert back to 3.2.0 as a workaround.