# React not working on IE11 and older Android browsers

Tags: reactjs

My React.js app currently does not work with IE11 or older Android browsers, despite having used the following code in the beginning of the index.js file:

```js
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

I have also tried the following:

```js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

I also tried importing all 4 at the same time. Still nothing. 
In my package.json, the browser list is:

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

I use many external npm libraries, and unsure what I need to do to make my code work with IE11 and older browsers. Does anyone know what else I can try? All solutions I have seen revolve around either core-js / react-app-polyfill or the browserlist.

**Edit:**

Screenshot of the error

[image: Error]
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604843/how-do-i-make-my-react-app-work-on-edge-and-ie-11

Comment: The error I get is not the same - updating my original question to include the error. thanks

Comment: make sure that you add the poly-fills import at the top of your `index.js` file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs map undefined in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540970/reactjs-map-undefined-in-ie10)

Comment: following up, it is probably because you did not import it on your index.js

Comment: I've already imported react-app-polyfill (/ie11 and /stable) on top of index.js but no change. I've then tried importing core-js/stable as per the post but that did not work either. Then I imported all 4. All at the top of index.js

Comment: @AlexM88 In the link I've posted, in the comments section, I demonstrate how to use `es-check` to see what files aren't ES5 compatible. Please follow those directions and report what you find.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thanks - Actually digging into the bundle 0.check.js I deduced the package creating this issue was filepond - and they have their own specific pollyfill. Will post answer to help anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pollyfill methods above do work well, but I had a package that required its own extra pollyfill.

Package in question - Filepond : https://github.com/pqina/filepond

Pollyfill: https://github.com/pqina/filepond-polyfill